# NestJs authentication using jwt and private and public key

Tags: authentication, passport.js, nestjs, jwt

I'm trying to understand jwt and authentication using nestJS.
I've created two separate microservices, one of them is an auth service, after successful login the client gets jwt token and with this token he can access to the other microservice.

Here is the code of the JwtStrategy and AuthModule of the auth service :

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey'
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And here is the code of the other service:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

I've figured out that there is no sense in using the same secret key for both services(because if I will create 10 microservices I won't use the same key for all of them) so I create a private and public key using openssl.
At the AuthModule, I copy the private key instead of the 'secretKey' string and at the other service I copy the public key instead of the 'secretKey' string but I get a 401, unauthorized error.
What have I missed here? why the JwtStrategy doesn't verify the public key?

Answer (score 21):

Since it's been days, I am guessing this was solved. I am just adding my two cents here for future readers.

The problem lies with the JwtModule and the JwtStrategy instantiation. They aren't configured properly. You need to pass in the algorithms you'd use for signing and verifying the tokens, along with the keys. To verify whether the tokens are actually getting generated with the RS256 algo, check the header in the token at https://jwt.io/. It would probably show HS256, and since your code didn't use the correct algorithm to sign the token. And it fails while token gets verified using the public key.

To generate signed tokens properly with the RSA key pair:

- You need to add algorithm in the signOptions as **RS256** and pass in the the **public** and **private** keys in the JwtModule configuration.
- Then within your service, you'd generate the token with the **PRIVATE_KEY** when you sign.
- JwtStrategy is used as a Guard. All it does is verify the JWT based on configuration. It expects either the **symmetric key "secret"** or the **"public part" of the asymmetric key** to verify. We have to use the PUBLIC_KEY. You also have to specify the algorithms to check for verifying here. We have to use **RS256** here as well, since we used that to generate the token.

**Auth Module**

```ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const options: JwtModuleOptions = {
          privateKey: configService.get('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
          publicKey: configService.get('JWT_PUB LIC_KEY'),
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: '3h',
            issuer: '<Your Auth Service here>',
            algorithm: 'RS256',
          },
        };
        return options;
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**Auth Service**

```ts
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async generateToken(
    user: User,
    signOptions: jwt.SignOptions = {},
  ): Promise<AuthJwtToken> {
    const payload = { sub: user.id, email: user.email, scopes: user.roles };
    return {
      accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload, signOptions),
    };
  }
}
```

**JwtStrategy**

```ts
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'),
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    const { sub: userId, email, scopes: roles } = payload;
    return {
      id: userId,
      email,
      roles,
    };
  }
}
```

In your other micro-services, You can use the same JwtStrategy we used in the Auth module.

Since you're creating a distributed app, you need to share the PUBLIC_KEY with the other micro-services by manually adding the key or by exposing it using some API endpoint. Either way, you have to use the **PUBLIC_KEY** for the other services to verify. You **must not** share or expose the **PRIVATE_KEY**.

*NOTE*: The following code assumes a ConfigService which would provide the RSA key pair form env. It's strongly suggested not to check in the keys in the code.

Comment: The env variables JWT_PRIVATE_KEY and JWT_PUB LIC_KEY are the string with the path where the private.pem and public.pem files are located?

Comment: Hey @JuanPabloMorenoMartín, the variables are the actual data/strings of the pem or crt files. If you check the config in the documentation, https://github.com/nestjs/jwt#secret--encryption-key-options, it expects them to be the actual values. You may have to read the files and return the data in the configService or export the value in the pem files in the env

Comment: @AvikSarkar how do you retrieve the public key through a HTTP call (usually, the auth server provides the publc keys through JWKS like AUTHSERVER/.well-known/jwks.json) ?

Comment: @ChristopheBlin So did u figured it out how..?? I need Help

Comment: there is an example of how to do it through jwks on the auth0 website https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/

Comment: why would you write an example and then suggest to not to do this?